# menubutton not working anymore after upgrade to cordova 5+cordova android 4.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

I've recently upgraded to cordova 5 and removed/recreated android platform in version 4.0.0 and uninstalled/reinstalled all plugins.

I also had to upgrade android sdk to sdk 22 instead of 21.

Since the update, I'm no more able to catch the menubutton event as described in [the cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton).

As it's still referenced in the edge docs, I assume it should still be working and I've seen nothing about this in the release notes.

back button is still working.

I tried to set the target-sdk to 19, it did not solve anything about the issue.

**Edit:**
I've dug into cordova source code and found in CordovaWebViewImpl.java I found a suspicious TODO comment :

```
   public void setButtonPlumbedToJs(int keyCode, boolean override) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                // TODO: Why are search and menu buttons handled separately?
                if (override) {
                    boundKeyCodes.add(keyCode);
                } else {
                    boundKeyCodes.remove(keyCode);
                }
                return;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported keycode: " + keyCode);
        }
    }
```

Well my answer would be "IT SHOULDN'T!!!!"

Cordova makes a list of keycode to handle but does not add the menu button and later on the keycode is compared to KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU only after the keycode has been skipped because it's not in the list.

I've tried to add a case for the menu button, but it turns out the function is only called with the code of the back button.

So now I know why it doesn't work but still not how to fix it.

**Edit 02/2016:**
As per [latest Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9949), the support of the menubutton is now fixed in java part in Cordova Android 5.1.0 but still not initialized from the javascript.
For the moment, as indicated by Jira user Keith Wong, you need to add a javascript call before you add your event listener :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    ...
    navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);  // <-- Add this line
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
    ...
}, false);
```

Comment: yes that's what I'm gonna do... as soon as a recall where to!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7248?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC

Comment: Thanks, I've found that the issue has already been reported a month ago, but it seems the people answering didn't really understood the issue and thinks menubutton only exists on old android 2.3 devices :( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8921

Comment: "Back in my days we used to have menubuttons...and we liked it that way!"

Comment: Thanks a lot for asking this question, thanks to you I had a strong lead, I'm going to "disable the boundKeyCodes check" as suggested by a decent user over the jira discussion, issues like these are pretty saddening, I have 10's of patches like these that I apply programmatically over various parts of cordova/plugins ...

Comment: It still won't work for me, Although I am on Cordova 5.41 now where it is supposed to be fixed https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/b6a329d479e15cdf8a7a30a8fea9c5799c73841a

Comment: A year later and the problem persists on cordova 6.x.

Comment: @Andrew, look at my last edit, you just need to call `navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);` to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

clarent's answer didn't do it for me, the menu button still didn't respond.

I tried several patches, one other suggestion to disable the boundKeyCodes check completely didn't do it either, because then the backbutton behaviour would be compromised.

The clean way to get the old behaviour back should be as follows.
The boundKeyCodes check ensures, that custom behaviour is only executed when there actually is a custom event handler bound to the event. But binding an event handler to "menubutton" in your app's JS code no longer triggers the menubutton key code to be added to the boundKeyCodes list. 
This is because the setButtonPlumbedToJs method is never executed for the "menubutton" handler in the first place AND even if it would, the switch statement in this method doesn't handle KEYCODE_MENU.

You can get that behaviour back quite easily, first you will have to apply the change suggested by clarent:

1. **Handle KEYCODE_MENU**

in CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CoreAndroid.java (around line 357, setButtonPlumbedToJs) add a case statement after the KEYCODE_BACK entry like this:

```
public void setButtonPlumbedToJs(int keyCode, boolean override) {
  switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
    // TODO: Why are search and menu buttons handled separately?
      if (override) {
        boundKeyCodes.add(keyCode);
      } else {
        boundKeyCodes.remove(keyCode);
      }
      return;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported keycode: " + keyCode);
  }
}
```

Then ensure that setButtonPlumbedToJs actually gets executed. You need two more changes for that.

2. **Add framework handler**

In CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CoreAndroid.java (around line 243, overrideButton) make the method look like this (add the last else-if clause):

```
public void overrideButton(String button, boolean override) {

  if (button.equals("volumeup")) {
    webView.setButtonPlumbedToJs(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP, override);
  }
  else if (button.equals("volumedown")) {
    webView.setButtonPlumbedToJs(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, override);
  }
  else if (button.equals("menubutton")) {
    webView.setButtonPlumbedToJs(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU, override);
  }
}
```

1. **Add javascript handler call**

In platform_www/cordova.js (around line 1532, bootstrap) change this line:

```
cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('menubutton');
```

to this:

```
var menuButtonChannel = cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('menubutton');
menuButtonChannel.onHasSubscribersChange = function() {
  exec(null, null, APP_PLUGIN_NAME, "overrideButton", ['menubutton', this.numHandlers == 1]);
};
```

This will trigger the frameworks overrideButton method as soon as an event handler is added to "menubutton".

That should do it. I also added this solution as a comment to
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8921
and might be filing a pull request shortly.

Comment: All that will be rebuilt and lost every time you re-add the Android platform (which is, esentially, every time you upgrade Cordova and/or the platform)

Answer (score 0):

Just add to function setButtonPlumbedToJs one line : **case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:**

```
public void setButtonPlumbedToJs(int keyCode, boolean override) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
```

So in onDispatchKeyEvent switch will work:

```
      } else if (boundKeyCodes.contains(keyCode)) {
                String eventName = null;
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                        eventName = "volumedownbutton";
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                        eventName = "volumeupbutton";
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                        eventName = "searchbutton";
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                        eventName = "menubutton";
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        eventName = "backbutton";
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now with cordova-android 5.1, the code has changed and my patch didn't work any-more (and sadly, with no patch the menu button is still not working in this version).

As I wanted to be able to upgrade the platform without having to review the code each time, I searched for a new way to get the menu button working again.

In cordova android 5.1 it turns out that everything is here in the java code for the button to be working, except that the menu button key is never added to the *boundKeyCoded* array.

It turns out that this array needs to be filled by a call from javascript (which is done for the back button and volume button, but neither for the search button or the menu button).

The code that is missing is something like that :

```
exec(null, null, APP_PLUGIN_NAME, 'overrideButton', ['menubutton' , true]);
```

(a js call to the java function *overrideButton* from **CoreAndroid.java** to tell to add the menu button key to the *boundKeyCodes* array.

I think this call should be added to *platform.js*, but since *platform.js* is used to build *cordova.js* during the platform add, I decided to make a **after_platform_add hook** that patchs the *cordova.js* file.

The advantage of this hook is that there's no java change and it should work even if you use a different webview like crosswalk.

So, first, in *config.xml*, in the android section add the hook :

```
<platform name="android">
    ....
    ....
    <hook type="after_platform_add" src="scripts/android/patch_menubutton.js" />
    ....
    ....
</platform>
```

Then, in the scripts folder add the hook file *patch_menubutton.js* :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
module.exports = function(ctx) {
    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
        path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path');
    var CordovaJSPath = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android/platform_www/cordova.js');
    var data = fs.readFileSync(CordovaJSPath, 'utf8');
    var result = data.replace(new RegExp("cordova\\.addDocumentEventHandler\\('menubutton'\\);", "g"), "cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('menubutton'); exec(null, null, APP_PLUGIN_NAME, 'overrideButton', ['menubutton' , true]);");
    fs.writeFileSync(CordovaJSPath, result, 'utf8');
}
```

(it looks for the initialisation of the event handler for the menu button and appends the call to the *overrideButton* function, like described in the last part of FewKinG's answer)

Comment: Ok, so now this is useless since you just need to call navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true); from javascript to initialize the button.